# Run JHipster in production profile - no database connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, tomcat7, jhipster

I have a problem with running JHipster in Production Mode. After building the .war by

```
mvn -Pprod package
```

and uploading it to my server, I get the "normal" start page - so the page loaded, but with following errors:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://server.net:9080/studentenhelfer-intern-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.original/api/authentication?cacheBuster=1459611519471"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://server.net:9080/studentenhelfer-intern-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.original/api/logout?cacheBuster=1459611519626"
```

The second point - when I "install/start" the Application on the server, the database will be not created. (No tables and no data)
I can´t figure out why.... With the dev-profile everything is working fine.... (Also with the same DB settings in application-prod.yml)

Additionial Info: the spring profile has also been set to prod profile in

```
/etc/default/tomcat7
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dspring.profiles.active=prod"
```

(This should be ok, yes?)
I´m using MySql as Db (with liquibase) and Maven for building. The server is a linux server (ubuntu) with Plesk 12.
For information - that´s my first experience with a linux-server. So maybe I forgot some extra configurations, but I think if the page gets loaded, the tomcat should not be the problem)

I also can´t find any "usefull" logs from catalina or tomcat...

```
var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
var/log/apache2/error.log
```

But if someone needs to see the logs, I will post them..

Please help :( 
Thanks, Fab

EDIT: I have tried to run the application on a local running tomcat -> And it works... so it´s a server-side problem?

Comment: Are you sure that your app is running in prod profile? DId you see it in log?

Comment: Not sure, the problem is that I didn´t get an specific log from starting the jhipster application, what I mean is that I can´t find any application startup log. So I thougt that the app didn´t start, but I can access the start/login page (without acces to the spring backend, the 404 not found´s) and in Plesk the app is shown as active. So the only error message I get is in the catalina.out log file:

Comment: sorry: .... So there is an error message I get in the catalina.out log file:Unknown default host [localhost] for connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9080]] (There are some more but not java/spring/Jhipster specific) An yes, how I wrote, I set the option in the tomcat7 file. So I don´t have any idea :/ How can I check if it´s on runtime in prod profile? I didn´t find more log files in tomcat, which are throwing some exceptions cause of the db-connection or something else...

Comment: But yes - if the same .war file is running on my local tomcat7 server and not on the remote server (which I use with Plesk, maybe this is mixing up some configs), it only could be the cause of the spring profile or it´s a server specific problem..

Comment: so here ist the logging part from catalina.out: http://pastebin.com/QUXTwd7a

Comment: The log you pasted is the log from tomcat itself not your application log, so maybe your logback-spring.xml is not configured correctly. If you are unable to set prod profile, remove application-dev.yml and rename application-prod.yml to application-dev.yml and re-package, the default profilme is dev so it should work.

Comment: By the way, why do you use Tomcat 7? When it is embedded sring boot uses Tomcat 8. And why not using embedded Tomcat?

Comment: At first, thanks Gael! Yes I forgot to set the logger correctly.. And now I suspecting a bigger problem: I set the logger file and rebuild/deploy it. But I can´t find the logger files anyway.. So now after a long time googling, the reason could be following: How I said - I´m using Plesk Administration tools (For "easy" deployment). And in the server.xml file of tomcat, the following attribute "unpackWARs='false'" for the webapp is set. That could be a problem, or? However, I can´t find any log file with the standard logging settings (the commented code in logback-spring)

Comment: And sorry again, I´m really new to linux, maybe I forgot something ... Where will the log files appear normaly? in var/logs or in a specific directory? If there is no solution, I will try to deploy the app without Plesk..

Comment: I don't know Plesk so I don't know if it adds any value in your case. The log files location depends a lot on your Tomcat setup (could be /var/lib/tomcat7/logs) but you can override them for your own app in logback configuration to write anywhere.

Comment: Yes me too, I thought it would be easy to use Plesk to set easily further updated and security options, bur now I´m not sure if it´s better to install and maintain it all by my self... But to the logs again, i set the fileNamePattern of the log to a specific unique name, so I can search for it. But I can´t find it by "find / -name 'logiflename*'". So I think it will not be created..

Comment: I would not install Tomcat either, I would just use the executable war. This way you are sure that what you test locally is the same as what you run in production

Comment: Ok, so you said it´s embedded (I never work before with embedded tomcat) - can you tell me please what I need to set-up/start the app with the embedded tomcat 8 and not with the tomcat7 on my server? ... In the meantime I will seach for more information.. Thanks...

Comment: Ok I found it...
http://jhipster.github.io/production/

Comment: But is it as simply as it is written? Is the directory not important? So I only upload the file on the server and run this? (How I said, I never work with that) Thanks for your patience...

Comment: Yes that's the beauty of spring-boot

Comment: Ok, but then this happens... https://picload.org/image/rggdcccr/errorwar.jpg

Comment: (Same with the additional spring prod profile setting)

Comment: Is the problem maybe that I use OpenJDK ?

Comment: When I try to run the other war file (not the original) this appears:
https://picload.org/image/rggdcwgp/errorwar.jpg
Maybe I install tomorrow a clean Debian distr. on my server and don´t use Plesk, I think that´s one of the reason, why it could not working... Only downloading the jdk and than uploading the war and executing it. If you have more tips - please let me know!

Comment: Not related to OpenJDK. The original war is not executable, use the normal one. Read the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar

Comment: Your server uses wrong version of jdk, jhipster requires jdk 8. What does `java -version` display?

Comment: Okay thanks Gael, after long trial and fail I choosed to reinstall the entire server. Now I´m using Debian 8 and everything works fine! I installed the whole software manually (Not by Plesk). Maybe it´s "better" for beginners to start without and administration ui, because then you know which config is set and vice versa. 
Now I´m starting liking jhipster more and more (and spring boot specificly). It´s nice how easy it works! Thanks for your help. Have a nice day :)